# Phonegap: show HTML/Progressbar splashscreen because i need to download resources

Tags: javascript, cordova

I read some posts on stackoverflow about having SplashScreens with a loading spinner or similar.
But its always done in Java for Android using Activities.
Phonegap allows me to download files using FileTransfer.download.

I would like to show a splashscreen with a progress bar which i change whenever the onProgress event fires for FileTransfer.download in javascript.

Lets say i have a simple phonegap app which has only one image for the splashscreen and the phonegap javascript library to use FileTransfer.download.

I would show the splashscreen and load the resources (images, html, css, etc.) in the background and update the progressbar accordingly. After it has finished i would close that splashscreen.

Is there any problem doing this the HTML way, since for the splashscreen there is not much to load it, the whole shebang will be loaded in the background.

No matter if this is on iOs or Android, it should work or?
Isn't that possible?

Comment: `<progress></progress>`

Comment: @Virus721: Interesting answer, does that mean it works? Its not a question about how to do it, its a question about if there is any concern doing it, since nearly everyone only uses the in-built splashscreen and no html.

Comment: Not a coding related question then.

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes you can use Simple CSS and HTML to load spinner.

```
https://codepen.io/mandelid/pen/vwKoe
```

Get the Html and CSS codes accordingly ( you might need to change the code little bit ) and hide and show the div accordingly with Javascript or jquery.

2) But the easiest solution will be using SpinnerDialog phonegap plugin.Because in some situation it is hard to get the view on top of some screens( eg:inappbrowser)

https://github.com/Paldom/SpinnerDialog.git

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/Paldom/SpinnerDialog.git
```

Then use following methods on anywhere.

- `window.plugins.spinnerDialog.show`
- `window.plugins.spinnerDialog.hide`